# NetLogo error message with >, < symbols

Tags: netlogo

I code with NetLogo for my seller buyer model. 
And when I code this part so:

```
ask sellers [if any? buyers-here [set seller_Price seller_Price > ownCosts ]]
```

I get this error :

> The > operator can only be used on two numbers, two strings, or two
>   agents of the same type, but not on a TRUE/FALSE and a number. error
>   while seller 73 running >   called by procedure INTERACTION   called
>   by procedure GO   called by Button 'GO'

Can anyone say what should I change in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear what you are trying to say, but it appear you want `seller_Price` to be a boolean (since `seller_Price > ownCosts` must return a boolean), but then you also want to compare it to a number (`ownCosts`).  You cannot do this.

Here is an example of something you can do (inside a procedure).

```
let mean-price mean [seller_Price] of sellers
ask sellers [set seller_Price max (list mean-price ownCosts)]
```

As Seth indicated, if you want to set `seller_Price` to a number, you have to say exactly how to produce that number.  In response to your second comment, if you want to set `seller_Price` to a random value that is up to `ownCosts + 2`, then you just do that:

```
ask sellers [set seller_Price (ownCosts + random-float 2)]
```

See http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#random-float for details.

Separately, just fyi, it is most common in the NetLogo community to hyphenate variable names (e.g., `own-costs` rather than `ownCosts`).

Comment: I want to say here that the seller_Price of my sellers has to be bigger than ownCosts of my seller. isnt the right coding?

Comment: It isn't enough to say you want it to be some value which is bigger. You have to specify exactly how much bigger you want it to be. For example, if you want to make it 2 bigger, you would write `set seller_Price ownCosts + 2`.

Comment: i want to set seller_Price bigger than ownCosts but i can not say how much. may be i can write it random number not excately for example 2. Is there any way to code it?

Comment: I code it but now i have problem with another process in my model because of this "random-float". ://

Comment: i can send you my model if you want to check it

Comment: and one more question: I tried it with random-float but what I want to do is that to set my seller_Price bigger than my ownCosts, and it must be a random number. But when I write this code:
ask sellers [set seller_Price (ownCosts + random-float 2)]
my seller_Price will be something 2,....... but not 4,5. or 1041 someshing else. Could I explain my problem?

Comment: It sounds like you want a different distribution, without an upper bound.  Maybe a Poisson distribution? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution  You can have this by changing `random-float 2` to `random-poisson 2`.  Or if you want fractional values as well you could try `random-exponential 0.5`.